# How to get Price of a Stock in different exchanges using yahoo finance

Tags: stock-markets, yahoo-finance

How to get the Price of a Stock in different exchanges using yahoo finance.

For example, consider EEENF

For US stocks:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EEENF?p=EEENF&.tsrc=fin-srch

And I found for Australian Market:

https://www.finance.yahoo.com/quote/88e.ax?p=88e.ax

How get similar to above in UK Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! Finance uses Exchange Suffixes to specify single name equity quotes by exchange. I found that list of suffixes here: [Exchanges and Data Providers on Yahoo Finance](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/exchanges-data-providers-yahoo-finance-sln2310.html)

The London Stock Exchange (or as you termed, UK Exchange) suffix is **.L** so **88E.L** would be the ticker used to get the 88 Energy Limited equity quote from the London Stock Exchange.

[88 Energy Limited London Stock Exchange Quote](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/88E.L?p=88E.L&.tsrc=fin-srch)

**.AX** is the Australian Stock Exchange suffix which is how you specified the Australian Market quote, **88E.AX** in your example.

Comment: I'm hungry for rep...if my response is appropriate, accept the answer?